# How can I get the key values ​from the order I want in MultiMap?

Tags: java, minecraft

In MultiMap, I need to receive and process values ​​sequentially. I can't use the `".get"` method because it pulls all values. What I need is a code like `".get(key, 12)"` that returns the 12th value

This is how I created the MultiMap.

```
public static Multimap<String, Player> players = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

Comment: What's wrong with getting all values? You can still pick the 12th from "all values". How about `get(key).get(11)`?

Comment: I can't get all the values ​​because the values ​​I will get will come as UUIDs and I have to process them one by one and convert them to the player name.

Comment: And how does "the values ​​I will get will come as UUIDs and I have to process them one by one and convert them to the player name" prevent you from getting all the values exactly? Please demonstrate with some code.

Comment: **Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer(callFile.players.get(name)).getName());** This is how I return the player name. This form of conversion accepts a single value. Maybe there is another shortcut for me to do this but I don't know. If I can get the values ​​in order I can loop it and translate all the values. By the way **.get(key).get(11)** didn't work.

Comment: no such method found : [link](https://i.ibb.co/BPWz3Ch/Ekran-g-r-nt-s-2023-03-24-130008.png)